# RShiny : mainPanel behavior changing with input

Tags: r, shiny, widget

There is an action button above each picture. But it is working differently depending on the parity of input$n (in numeric input within sidebar panel).
If input$n is odd, clicking on the button changes the label, which is what I want.
Else, It does not.

Please find attached the server and ui respectively :

```
require(png)
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)

########## PRE-PROCESSING
Nsub <- 5
Nimg <- 10
nvar <- 112*92
N <- Nsub * Nimg

#stocker noms fichiers et images
init <- function(){
  listFiles <- list()
  listDataMat <- list()
  excluded <- list()
  
  for( sub in 1:Nsub ){
    listLabel <- c()
    DataMat <- matrix(nrow=Nimg,ncol=nvar)
    for( img in 1:Nimg ) {
      fname <-  paste("www/s",sub,"_",img,".png",sep="")
      listLabel <- c(listLabel,fname)
      d <- readPNG(fname)
      DataMat[img,] <- matrix(d,ncol=nvar)
    }
    listFiles[[sub]] <- listLabel
    listDataMat[[sub]] <- DataMat
    excluded[[sub]] <- rep(FALSE,10)
  }
  
  list(listFiles,listDataMat,excluded)
}

lists <- init()
listFiles <- lists[[1]]
listDataMat <- lists[[2]]
excluded <- lists[[3]] #noms fichier exclus de database // %in%
remove(lists)


############ HELPER FUNC
#afficher images d'une classe
dispImgs <- function(variable,ind){
  
  if(variable>=1){
    DataMat <- listDataMat[[variable]]
  }else{
    DataMat <- listDataMat[["0"]]
  }
  result <- list()
  outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  
  sample <- matrix(DataMat[ind,], nrow = 112, ncol = 92)
  writePNG(sample, target = outfile)
  im <- list(src = outfile,
             contentType = "image/png",
             alt = "Normalement, on devrait voir une photo",
             width = 92, 
             height = 112
  )
  im
}


###########SERVER
server <- function(input,output,session){
  excluded <- reactiveValues(ls = excluded)
  
  # vals <- reactiveValues()
  # vals$n_sample <- 10
  # vals$n_rows <- *
  # vals$last_row <- n_sample%%5
  # 
  observeEvent(input$n,{
    n_sample <- ifelse(input$n==0,nrow(listDataMat[["0"]]),nrow(listDataMat[[input$n]]))
    n_rows <- round(n_sample/5)
    last_row <- n_sample%%5
    
    #creating event listener
    lapply(
      X = 1:n_sample,
      FUN = function(i){
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("out",i)]], {
          excluded$ls[[input$n]][i] <- !excluded$ls[[input$n]][i]
          updateActionButton(session, paste0("out",i),
                             label = ifelse(excluded$ls[[input$n]][i],"Inclure","Exclure"))
          print(excluded$ls[[input$n]])
        })
      }
    )
  })
  
  img_widget <- function(i) {
    if(input$n==0){
      column(2,
             renderImage({
               dispImgs(input$n,i)
             },outputArgs = c(height="200px")
             )
      )
      
    }else{
      column(2,
             actionButton(paste0("out",i), label = ifelse(excluded$ls[[input$n]][i],"Inclure","Exclure")),
             renderImage({
               dispImgs(input$n,i)
             }, 
             outputArgs = c(height="200px")
             )
      )
      
    }
    
  }
  
  output$mainPanel <- renderUI({
    mainPanel(
      h2(paste("Les 10 photos de l'individu", input$n)),
      # if(n_rows!=0){
      #   for(i in 1:n_rows){
      #     fluidRow(
      #       width=10,
      #       lapply(
      #         X = 1+5*(i-1):5*i,
      #         FUN = img_widget
      #       )
      #     )
      #   }
      # }
      # if(last_row!=0){
      #   fluidRow(
      #     width=10,
      #     lapply(
      #       X = 1+5*(n_rows-1):5*(n_rows-1)+last_row,
      #       FUN = img_widget
      #     )
      #   )
      # }
      fluidRow(
        width=10,
        lapply(
          X = 1:5,
          FUN = img_widget
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        width=10,
        lapply(
          X = 6:10,
          FUN = img_widget
        )
      )
    )
    
  })
  
}
```

```
require(png)
require(shiny)

######### HELPER FUNC


########## UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Titre
  headerPanel("Banque de photos pour reconnaissance faciale"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('n', "Numéro de l'individu à afficher", 1, min = 0, max = 40, step = 1)
    ),
  uiOutput("mainPanel")
  )
)
```

In order to reproduce the problem, you need a folder 'www' containing pictures named 's1_2.png' where 1 is the class and 2 is the picture index.
You may only define 5 pictures for each class (S[1-5]_[1-5].png). Hence there will be a natural minor display problem.

Edit : Forgot to mention that the pictures need to be in grey levels.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your example, I got an error at the `DataMat[img,] <- matrix(d,ncol=nvar)` line where it is supposed to replace one line of the existing `DataMat` matrix with a new matrix containing 3 rows (obtained from the readPNG function). How are you able to run that line?

Comment: Good Point, you may have this error because my pictures are in grey levels. Sorry forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `print(excluded$ls[[input$n]])` output, it seems that each time the `input$n` is triggered, it increments the number of `updateActionButton()` that will be launched when triggering any `input$outN`.

So for example, triggering 2 times `input$n` and then clicking on any `input$outN` button will launch the `updateActionButton` twice instead of once. So it first excludes but then reincludes your sample. When `input$n` has been triggered an odd number of times, it finally ends wit an exclusion of the sample so that's why it *seems* to work.

Not sure exactly why that happens, but it's definitely because there are two nested `observeEvent`. Similar behavior may have been observed (pun intended) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035083/nesting-two-observeevents-duplicates-the-reactive-event).

If you don't nest the two `observeEvent`, it works as expected:

```
n_sample <- nrow(listDataMat[[1]])

observeEvent(input$n,{
n_sample <- ifelse(input$n==0,nrow(listDataMat[["0"]]),nrow(listDataMat[[input$n]])) 
n_rows <- round(n_sample/5)
last_row <- n_sample%%5
})

#creating event listener
lapply(
  X = 1:n_sample,
  FUN = function(i){
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("out",i)]], {
      excluded$ls[[input$n]][i] <- !excluded$ls[[input$n]][i]
      updateActionButton(session, paste0("out",i),
                         label = ifelse(excluded$ls[[input$n]][i],"Inclure","Exclure"))
      print(excluded$ls[[input$n]])
    })
  }
)
```

But you need to define the `n_sample` variable outside of the first `observeEvent` so it can be used by the `lapply` function. I simplified by defining it "statically" but you'll need some `reactiveValue` so it can be updated when triggering the first `observeEvent`.

Comment: Ty. it helped me solve my problem.