# dynamic reactive buttons, update variables

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am using the answer of the following code to create an arbitrary number of action events ushing this code:

[Dynamic number of actionButtons tied to unique observeEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157684/dynamic-number-of-actionbuttons-tied-to-unique-observeevent)

What I would like to do is now used the observe event to change a reactive value, so this part of the code:

```
local({
    i <- ii
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input[[paste0("button",i)]],
                 handlerExpr = {print(sprintf("You clicked btn number %d",i))
                 my_reactive() <- i
})
  })
```

The problem is that i get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
[No stack trace available]
```

I presume that its because of the scoping of using local, but cant find a way to either remove the local part.

Comment: This statement `my_reactive() <- i` is an issue.  You may not be able to modify the reactive object that way.  Try `reactiveValues` object.

Comment: my_reactive is assigned before the for loop, my_reactive<-reactiveVal(), not sure how i would use reactiveValues in this context, or why would it change the behaviour

Comment: If it is a `reactiveVal`, you can just state `my_reactive(i)`, instead of `my_reactive() <- i`.

Comment: it seems that made the trick! thank you!